# Exportar datos a xls

Tags: r

¿cómo puedo exportar en R un fichero a formato xls?

no xlsx, ni csv, sino xls.

Podría exportarlo a csv, abrirlo con el excel y guardalo como xls, pero me gustaría saber si hay una forma directa con R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la librería xlsx se puede

```
xlsx::write.xlsx(iris,"iris.xls",row.names = F)
```

Donde uso el parámetro row.names = F para que no me escriba los nombres de las filas

Observación: Esta librería a veces tiene problemas para instalarse, por lo que recomiendo instalarla en una versión de R que coincida con la que tienes de java.

O bien puedes setear la versión de R a gusto desde:

Tools/Global Options.../General/Rversion: le das change a la versión de tu java